# How to cross join KsqlDB tables or streams?

Tags: join, ksqldb, cross-join

I want to cross join 2 KsqlDB Tables. For example:

### Country Table

| data_id | country |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Malaysia |
| 102 | Singapore |

### Product Table

| data_id | product |
| --- | --- |
| 301 | pen |
| 302 | book |

The result should be:

### Country_Product Table

| country_data_id | country | product_data_id | product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Malaysia | 301 | pen |
| 101 | Malaysia | 302 | book |
| 102 | Singapore | 301 | pen |
| 102 | Singapore | 302 | book |

I tried to google the solution, but I have no luck. All information that I found are inner join or outer join only.

Answer (score 0):

Add another dummy column in both of your tables namely join_id. And populate the column with the value 1 (Both tables, each row). Now do the inner join, you will get the expected result.